# How do you eliminate spaces from a list? Python

Tags: python, list, text-files

```
val = []

for c in f:

    val.append(ord(c))

val = [w - 5 if w > 20 else w for w in val]
```

The original text file contains a sentence which has many spaces in it. When converting the text file into its ASCII code it also converts the spaces into its ASCII code.

Comment: Can you show a sample of the file you are reading and your exact expected output?

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I cannot see what your code has to do with the question in the title.

Comment: @timgeb the code shows him converting characters to int. It's perfectly relevant IMO.

Comment: @user161778 what has getting the ordinal of a character to do with removing spaces from a list? What has the random list comprehension to do with removing spaces from a list?

Comment: @timgeb he's clearly building a list in `val`. I found the question clear and I answered it fine.

Comment: @user161778 Thank you very much for answering,  you have been a lot of help :)

Comment: @user3801907 if his answer helped, you can accept it or upvote.

Answer (score 2):

In your for loop, change `f` to `f.replace(' ','')`.  That will remove spaces.

This code should work:

```
val = []

for c in f.replace(' ',''):

    val.append(ord(c))

val = [w - 5 if w > 20 else w for w in val]
```

Comment: Rather than do a replace (which would use two loops), I believe it's best to just check for the character. I mean, he's already looping through the string.

Answer (score 0):

From `c in f` and `ord(c)` I am assuming `f` is a `str`. The `if c` filter eliminates spaces.

```
codes = (ord(c) for c in f if c)
# codes is a genex. Now you can use it any way you want, e.g
codes_ = [code-5 if code > 20 else code for code in codes]
```

Answer (score -1):

Currently your for loop appends the value every character it finds in `f` to `val`. The variable `c` holds the character about to be added, so you can simply check for the presence of `' '` beforehand with an `if` statement:

```
val = []

for c in f:
    if c != ' ':
        val.append(ord(c))

val = [w - 5 if w > 20 else w for w in val]
```